# Android Fragment/Tabs and Pager: Tab names wrap

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I`m trying to build a application using the  Fragment/Tabs and Pager from the android support v4 library. I want to make my application android 2.3 compatible but i have problem. It is visible on the screenshot: the tab name does wrap. I want to have around 20-40 tabs and to be able to navigate with swipe (as seen in the market application).

Screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/device20120207161609.png/

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
}
```

xml

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to check out this project:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

And use the ViewPagerIndicator instead of tabs. The TabActivity is deprecated anyway.

Comment: this looks awesome, probably it is what i was looking for